# Lag when trying to implement parallax effect in swift (spritekit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, parallax, lag, gravity

I am trying to create game in SpriteKit with parallax effect, but when I implement my method, my hero lags (quickly shakes) from time to time (no pattern observed)...

I wrote this simple code that illustrates the method and also contains the same problem.

The hero should stay in the center of the screen and only his position relative to his parent (foreground) should change. But it lags (quickly shakes for a really short moment) every now and then. I also noticed that when I run the game, the hero sinks down very, very slowly a few pixels (maybe 5-10) before it starts holding its position after ~15 sec.

I can't figure out what is causing this behavior. Any help would be appreciated. I am testing on IPhone 6.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


let hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")
let foreground = SKNode()


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)


    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -0.5)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


    // anchor point of scene is at (x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    hero.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false


    addChild(foreground)
    foreground.addChild(hero)
}


override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    foreground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(hero.position.y))
}
}

// I need the foreground to move in opposite direction so I can add stars,
// monsters, etc while keeping the player in the view... Update method does 
// this: hero is pulled down by gravity so his y position would be -1 pixel 
// relative to foreground but I assign foreground the opposite y-position of
// hero (+1) and since hero's position relative to foreground is -1, he should 
// be positioned at y-position = 0 which, in this code example, should create 
// an illusion that he is positioned at the center and doesn't move
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the purpose of code snippet from update method, because you say that hero is always centred and not moving.  And foreground's position is directly related with hero's position in your example. Can you explain better what you are trying to achieve? Anyways, try to change hero.physicsBody?.dynamic to false (if possible) and that would probably stop shaking effect.

Comment: This is just a simplified version of my code for better testing purposes. I will need the hero to jump etc. but at first I need to get rid of this annoying lag. I updated the code preview with the commentary of what the update function does (it is right at the bottom). Hope it helps

Comment: I've tried to make simple example by myself (both in Obj-C and Swift)  and I have noticed something which can be called a lag (in simulator). Maybe this has something with your physics world settings, because default is dx = 0.0, and dy = -9.8 so maybe you should try with default settings just see what will happen. Are you trying to simulate water(I guess not :)) with such a low gravity? If yes, maybe you could try with setting linear dumping to some high value. In that way, where gravity is set to higher values I had no any lag.

Comment: i did few more experiments and conlcuded that gravity & update func that contains an object that's being pulled by gravity dont work together as expected. simple experiment: forget foreground and do something like: addChild(hero), gravity dy: -50, and in update func: hero.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.size.height/2) -> I would expect hero to stay at  (frame.size.height/2) position but he is pulled by gravity to off screen and then every 5 secs appears on screen for a sec - weird :D ..nevertheless I solved my problem by simply changing update func with didSimulatePhysics func. thnx for help